# Converting from Linux to MacOS Date Commands

Tags: linux, bash, macos, date, sh

I’m trying to run a script which has been written for Linux on my Mac and I’m struggling to run some `date` commands - I know I can convert them to `gdate`, however I’m unable to install `gdate` on my device. As a consequence, I need to manually convert the commands.

The first command is of the form

```
val=$(date -d “$1” + %Y%m%d)
```

where $1 would be something like `2020-01-01`

I think this can be converted into something like (on MacOS):

```
val=$(date -j -f “%Y-%m-%d” “$1” +%s)
```

but I’m not 100% sure if this is correct.

The second command is of the form

```
val2=$(date -d “$d” +^%d/%b/%Y);
```

and finally

```
date -d “$d + $i day” +%Y%m%d

date -d “$d” +%Y-%m-%d)
```

I’m struggling with converting these as well.

Comment: Please, check your commands. The first : is with unbalanced double cotes and not use ASCII quotes. There is a space after "`+`" symbol. It can't be between "`+`" and  format. The second, What is "`-j`" option. Unknow with my `date` version under GNU/Linux. `-f` option accept a filename, not a format... So I don't understand what you really want. Write a complete example of transformation from what you have to what you want

Comment: Do you have a macOS (or even BSD) machine to test your translations? The main thing missing is that GNU `date` doesn't let you specify the input format for `-d`, but rather tries to parse a wide variety of formats itself. BSD `date` doesn't do any kind of inference, but lets you specify the exact format you want using the same `%` placeholders. (BSD `date` also does not do date arithmetic with the input, but provides a `-v` option that I find preferable in many situations.)

Comment: Also, it seems to be much more straightforward to install GNU `date` on a macOS box (compared to installing BSD `date` on a Linux box), if that's an option. Then you don't have to convert from one to the other.

Comment: @Alk: _ I’m unable to install gdate_ Why? This would be the cleanest solution, after all.

Comment: @ArnaudValmary I fixed the fist command. As to the -j option, this is for macOS - it works correctly when I run it. I also don’t have access to third party libs from this mac so can’t install anything like gdate.

Comment: I don't have a mac. Without explanation and full example, it's difficult to write a response

Comment: @ArnaudValmary here’s an explanation of -j and -f: 
-f      Use input_fmt as the format string to parse the new_date provided rather than using the default [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss] format.
      Parsing is done using strptime(3).

     -j      Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the -f flag in addition to the + option to convert one date format to another.

https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/date/